# how to fetch data from local object in React Native using Redux Toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to fetch data from Local object using Redux toolkit.
Everything is good but when trying to dispatch the data I get undefined.
here is my code:
**homeScreen**

```js
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import localObjectSlice from "../redux/store";
import {setData} from "../redux/reducer";
export default function HomeScreen({navigation}) {

  const localObject = {
    data: [
      {id: 1, name: "Item 1"},
      {id: 2, name: "Item 2"},
      {id: 3, name: "Item 3"},
    ],
  };
  // const data = useSelector(state => state.localObject.data);
  const data = useSelector(state => state.localObject.data);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(localObjectSlice.actions.setData(localObject.data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{alignItems: "center"}}>
      <View>
        {data.map(item => (
          <Text key={item.id}>{item.name}</Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**reducer**

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const localObjectSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'localObject',
  initialState: {
    data: []
  },
  reducers: {
    setData: (state , action) => {
      state.data = action.payload;
    }
  }
});


export const { setData } = localObjectSlice.actions;

export default localObjectSlice.reducer;
```

**store.js**

```js
import {configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import localObjectSlice from './reducer';
 const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    localObject: localObjectSlice
  },
});
export  default store;
```

I tried to get the data but I keep getting **SetData** is undefined
how can Isolve it?
this is only test but I have big data and it keeps me confusing when trying to past data over childersn and it makes my app slow

Answer (score 0):

you are setting it wrong, do this hope it resolves

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setData(localObject.data));
  }, []);
```